# Запуск Erlang демона

Tags: erlang, daemon

Я планирую создать демона на Erlang который будет получать задачи из RabbitMQ выполнять по ним HTTP запросы и результаты отдавать обратно в RabbitMQ.

Вопрос заключается в том, какие способы демонизации принято использовать в Erlang: собственные модули, внешние скрипты, что то еще?

Как правильно выполняется перезапуск, обновление кода демона?

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска демона использовать [run_erl](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/index.html).

Как пример: `run_erl -daemon /tmp "erl"`

Answer (score 0):

Можно запускать через run_erl http://erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html

либо же через http://smarden.org/runit/

с параметрами `-noinput -boot start_sasl -s module_name:start/0`